# What’s the best way to extract the State code from all types of addresses?

Tags: javascript, string, slice

I’m trying to figure out how to extract the State code from any type of address.

```
“123 Sunny Dr., Los Angeles, CA 90210, US”
“123 Sunny Lane, Unit B, Los Angeles, CA 90210, USA”
“123 Sunny Ct, Hollywood, CA, USA”
“Los Angeles, CA, US”
```

For any of these, I would just like the return value to be `“CA”`

Answer (score 1):

I would use `match` here with an alternation containing all US state codes:

```js
var addresses = ["123 Sunny Dr., Los Angeles, CA 90210, US", "123 Sunny Lane, Unit B, Los Angeles, CA 90210, USA", "123 Sunny Ct, Hollywood, CA, USA", "Los Angeles, CA, US"];
var states = addresses.map(x => x.match(/\b(?:AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|DC|FL|GA|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|OH|OK|OR|PA|PR|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VA|VI|WA|WV|WI|WY)\b/));
for (var i=0; i < addresses.length; ++i) {
    console.log(addresses[i] + " => " + states[i]);
}
```

We could try to formulate the state code as being a two letter uppercase letter word, but that runs the risk of matching `US`, which isn't a state code, but rather a country code.  A hard-coded alternation works here as there are less than 100 total state/territory codes for the US.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're getting just one string, you can

- create a function that takes a string as an argument
- split the passed in string on "," into an Array
- get the second last value in the Array into a variable
- remove whitespace and numbers, using a regex into another variable
- return this last variable